# Do you have to provide evidence you're non-union member if you're claiming wage theft? If you're not a union member is impossible to prove you're not

Tags: united-states, labor-law

Do you have to provide evidence you're non-union member if you're claiming [wage theft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wage_theft)? If you're not a union member is impossible to prove you're not.

Comment: Your question seems to assume that wage theft cannot be committed against union members? It seems unlikely that that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

In [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) there is nothing in the Employment Rights Act 1996 saying you have to prove or disprove union membership if your employer breaches your [Right not to suffer unauthorised deductions](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/18/section/13?timeline=false) .

All you need to do is present [Complaints to employment tribunals](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/18/section/23?timeline=false) but being in a union may help with the paperwork and providing legal  advice etc